# Using bubble sort/swap to sort strings in c++

Tags: c++, sorting, swap

I'm very new to C++, and I cannot seem to figure this problem out. This code is just supposed to have the user enter a list of animals (no more than 25 animals, 30 letters long), then it will output them in the order they were entered and then also in alphabetical order (using bubble sort). I apologize if my code is hard to follow or understand.

Whenever I put in animals such as "dog", "cat", "fish" and terminate the list with a period, I usually get "Unhandled exception at 0x55b6d2f3 in CharacterStrings.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xcccccccc." but then other times I get "A buffer overrun has occurred in CharacterStringsList.exe which has corrupted the program's internal state."

I'm just very confused as to how to fix this. I tried to Google both of them but I couldn't seem to find any solution that would work for me (as I'm still a beginner and don't know how to do much of the more advanced code). I'm pretty sure the error is somewhere in my swap function (maybe?) but I can't seen to figure it out. Maybe a logic error? I've tried everything I can think of.

If you have questions or anything, let me know. Any help or suggestions would be much appreciated! Thank you in advance :)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

void getInput(char animals[][30]);
void outputLists(char animals[][30]);
void bubbleSort(char animals[][30], int n);
void Swap(char *a, char *b);


void getInput(char animals[][30])
{
    cout << "Please enter a list of animals, terminated by a period: " << endl;

    for(int i = 0; i < 25; i++)
    {
        cin >> animals[i];
        if(strcmp(animals[i], ".") == 0)
            break;
    }
}

void bubbleSort(char animals[][30], int size)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < size-1; i++)
        for(int j = 0; j < size-1; j++)
            if(animals[j] < animals[j+1])
                Swap(animals[j], animals[j+1]);
}

void Swap(char *a, char *b)
{
    char t[30];
    strcpy(t, a);
    strcpy(a, b);
    strcpy(b, t);
}

void outputLists(char animals[][30])
{
    //Output original list
    for(int i = 0; i < 25; i++)
    {
        if(strcmp(animals[i], ".") == 0)
            break;
        cout << animals[i] << endl;
    }

    //Output sorted list
    for(int i = 0; i < 25; i++)
        cout << animals[i] << endl;

}

int main()
{
    char animals[25][30];

    getInput(animals);

    cout << endl;
    bubbleSort(animals,25);

    outputLists(animals);


    cout << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `if(animals[j] < animals[j+1])` would work with `std::string`s, but not with C style char arrays.

Comment: @H2CO3 Is there a way to make it work with C style character arrays? (I've never used std::string before and don't really know what I'm doing). I'm not even really sure if that question makes sense..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `strcmp(s1, s2)` for comparing C-style strings. It returns a value less than zero if s1 is less than s2.

And one more hint: C-style strings are null-terminated strings (i.e. there is a zero value after a string itself), so you need an array of size at least n+1 for storing a string of length n. In your case, 30 is not enough but 31 is.

Comment: OH that makes sense, duh. My professor gave us a template for bubble sort, using integers, and I didn't even think about having to use strcmp instead. Thanks so much @Ivan

It's working much better, but I'm not really sure how to output the bubble sort now in my output function...?